# Normal Plane and Tangent Line of 2 intersected surfaces without a point

Tags: multivariable-calculus, tangent-line

Is there a way to find the normal plane and the tangent line to the following surfaces without having a point of intersection, I know you can use Newton-Raphson method to find the approximate intersection point but, is there any way or is even possible?

$$ 1) \hspace{0.3cm} x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 14  $$
$$ 2) \hspace{0.3cm} x + y + z = 6$$

Comment: What do you mean by tangent line? There are infinite tangent lines, as there are infinite curves on those surfaces.

Comment: I mean a point where there is a tangent line and a normal plane to both surfaces at the same time

Comment: Your question is much confused. Surfaces have normal lines and tangent planes, not vice versa. It is not at all clear what you are after. A common point to both surfaces where the normal lines and tangent planes are the same? That doesn't exist. There is a single line that is normal to both surfaces (to surface (1) twice). The tangent planes at the same points will be parallel, but not identical. There is no point where the two surfaces share a tangent plane. This can be easily seen if one recognizes what these surfaces are.